# xamarin command with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I'm coding Xamarin with MVVM and need some help.

I want to pass all my entries into a Command so I can put them in a list in the model view. But I don't know how? So I want all the entries to make together be parameters in a class "Entries".

Is there any other way to do this?

XAML

```
<StackLayout >
    <StackLayout BindingContext="EntriesEdit">
        <Entry Keyboard="Default" Text="{Binding entry1}"/>
        <Entry  Keyboard="Default" Text="{Binding entry2}"/>
        <Entry  Keyboard="Default" Text="{Binding entry3}"/>
        <Entry  Keyboard="Url" Text="{Binding entry4}"/>
        <Entry  Keyboard="Default" Text="{Binding entry5}">
    </StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="Save_Button" Command="{Binding AddEntries}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

```

```
AddEntriesCommand = new Command(async vm =>  await AddEntries(vm as Entries));
```

Function

```
public async Task AddSpace(Entries Entries)
{
    SpacesViewModel.Entrieslist.Add(Entries);
   await  _pageService.PopAsync();
}
```

Comment: not sure without seeing the viewmodel code, but at a guess you probably need to change the button in xaml to:
<Button x:Name="Save_Button" Command="{Binding AddEntries}" CommandParameter="{Binding EntriesEdit}"/>

Comment: If EntriesEdit contains the parameters (entry1..5) as properties, change to Command="{Binding AddEntriesCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding EntriesEdit}". Also change the Function name so that is refers to the same name as in the new Command statement.

Comment: This doesn't seem very MVVM to me. Your view model is supposed to represent the current state of the view at all times. This seems to me like you're maintaining state in the view and trying to then pass it backwards?

Comment: So in other words the MV should keep track on the changes done in the input field at all time and then just save them when the submit button is pressed?

Comment: Exactly. There are actually ways to do what you're trying to do, but they're really convoluted and involve writing converters etc to wrangle the data into a format needed to pass back to your view models. Your view model is supposed to present data in a format that your view can consume with minimal effort. When you find yourself trying to hack data format conversion logic into your views (by way of converters or whatever) it's a really good indication that your view model isn't doing its job properly.

Comment: Remember, the view model is really the heart and soul of your GUI. In theory you should be able to run your entire program with no views at all, e.g. integration testing calling methods on your view models and responding to property updates accordingly. The views are just the very last little bit of interfacing between your view model ("GUI") and the display and input devices etc.

Comment: This is especially true in Xamarin where the binding and data templating implementation is nowhere near as powerful or flexible as WPF.

Comment: okey! thanks that's very helpfull!